# how pass the null value using datetime datatype in asp.net and database is mysql?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, stored-procedures

i am using asp.net 2.0 and database is Mysql and
i am passing null value using datetime datatype to mysql table like this **duedate is datetime**

```
if (ddlTerms.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() != "--Select--")
   {
     DateTime createDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(ddlTerms.SelectedValue));
     oInvHeader.DueDate = createDate;
   }
   else
   {
    oInvHeader.DueDate =(how to write the code here)
   }
```

in **invoiceHeader.cs** code

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Text;

 private DateTime m_DueDate;

public DateTime DueDate
        {
            get
            {
                return m_DueDate;
            }
            set
            {
                m_DueDate = value;
            }
        }
```

pls help me
thank u
hemanth

Comment: pls check this link it is sql server like taht i have mysql        http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sd_patel/EnterNullValuesForDateTime11222005015742AM/EnterNullValuesForDateTime.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your `DueDate` property should be `nullable` to accept a null value.

Then you can assign the null value like..

```
oInvHeader.DueDate = null;
```

Here is, how we declare a `nullable` variable

```
DateTime? DueDate;
```

Comment: how to set the datetime poperty is null ( i am asking db r fields in asp.net)

Comment: what is this oInvHeader.DueDate ? are you using any code generation tool?

Comment: no on dataaccess layer i am using invoiceheader.cs so that class object is oinvHeader and duedate is the datetime datatype

Comment: Can you show me that cs file? you can edit your question and paste that cs file code.

Answer (score 0):

public virtual Nullable Variablename

it wil take default null

Answer (score 0):

```
class test
{ 
    public virtual Nullable<Int32> ReagentSupplyCode
     {
        get;
        set;
     }
}
```